# Define a Typescript index signature that uses a separate generic type for each field

Tags: typescript

Often times the keys of a record dictate the value, for example:

```js
const record = {
   [2]: 5,
   ["string"]: "otherString",
   ["there is"]: "a pattern"
}
```

In these case, **for every key of type K, the record has the value K**.
Here's how a syntax for this could exist (this is not valid Typescript):

```js
type DynamicIndex = {
    [key<T>: T]: T
}
```

So this would compile:

```js
const record: DynamicIndex = {
   [2]: 5,
   ["string"]: "otherString",
   ["there is"]: "a pattern"
}
```

And this wouldn't:

```js
const record: DynamicIndex = {
   [2]: "string",
   ["string"]: "otherString",
   ["there is"]: "a pattern"
}
```

Is there a way to emulate such a behavior? In my case the value is `Something<T>` and not literally `T`:

```
type ComplexCase<V> = {
    [key<K extends typeof V>: K]: Something<V[K]>
}
```

Comment: TypeScript can't represent "a non-numeric key" as a type (it would need to be something like `string and not \`${number}\`` and there's no `not`) so anything you do would need to use a generic constraint like `DynamicIndex<T>` and not a plain type like `DynamicIndex`.  Maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/W4VZvN) meets your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a function for this.
You may use Type Validation to ensure the passed value is valid

```
type conforms<T, V> = T extends V ? T : V
type validateDynamicIndex<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: validateDynamicValue<K, T[K]>
}
type validateDynamicValue<K, V> = 
| K extends number ? number
: K extends string ? (
  K extends `${string} ${string}` ? Uppercase<V & string>
  : Lowercase<V & string>
)
: K

function validateDynamicIndex<T>(record: conforms<T, validateDynamicIndex<T>>) {
  return record;
}

validateDynamicIndex({
  4: 4,
  'foo': 'bar',
  'baz baz': 'BAZ BAZ',

  5: 'asd', // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
  asd: 'QWE', // Type '"QWE"' is not assignable to type '"qwe"'.(2322)
  'spa ced': 'foo' // Type '"foo"' is not assignable to type '"FOO"'.(2322)
})
```